# Multiple react versions on a website

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

At the moment, I can load different react-version into a website e.g. via script-tag (which results in `window.React`) and via ModuleLoader/AJAX (which might result in `myFancyContext.React`).
This works just fine, even with the react-dev-tools.

A few years back, facebook reported issues with having multiple versions of react on a website. So my question is: Might there be complications with this behavior in the future or am I save as it works just fine.

Comment: I’d say pretty much _anything_ that you are trying to run two versions of in parallel has the potential to break something at some point ... Plus, all your website visitors would have to download two library versions instead of one. Whenever possible, avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's not that I want to use two different versions of react. It's more like, I build a widget for webpages which potentially might use React and even more potentially (is that a saying?) it might be using another version.
What I want to be sure of is, when I have React (and ReactDOM) in another scope, it won't lead to problems.

Comment: rule of thumb: never do that. update your widget if it breaks on newer versions of react.

Comment: @luschn it's not that I want to do it. when a user embeds the widget and he is also using react on his website, there might be 2 different versions on the same page. so its not a case of 'please don't do that' but more like 'what can I do if this happens?'  my strategy is to load my own version of react in a different scope so it won't bother the user's version.

Comment: the user will have to upgrade his react version then. that´s the correct strategy. loading your own version in addition is a very very very bad idea, no one does that. keep your widget updated, users can use older versions of your widget if they use older react version. that´s really no big deal and that´s how it always works.

Comment: i will put this in an answer, because that´s the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Keep your widget updated, users can use older versions of your widget in their package.json if they use older react version. Just use GIT and make sure you update the version correctly. You can see this in the Readme file of many libraries, specifying the version of React for the current version and the version of React for older versions. Do not add React to your plugin - what if you do that for every single widget and a user wants to use several of them? It would get bigger and bigger.